# Display function value on hover?

Tags: plotting

I have used Manipulate in conjunction with Plot to draw a function's graph and I would like to show the current x-axis value and function value while hovering over the function's plot.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `Tooltip` any use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{tbl},
  tbl = Table[Tooltip[{x, Sin[a x]}], {x, -Pi, Pi, .1}];
  ListLinePlot[tbl, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0]]
  ],
 {{a, 1, "a?"}, .1, 5, .1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Nice, straightforward coding and a result where the coordinates appear only when the cursor is on the curve. Only limitation is the granularity of the `Tooltip` iterator.

Comment: @dabd It would be considered gracious if you were to accept Nasser's solution (click the checkmark), since you consider it a good solution for you.

Answer (score 10):

Alternative that avoids the flicker of Tooltip (copying & adapting @Nasser):

```
f[x_, a_] := Sin[a x^3];
p = {0, 0};
Manipulate[
 EventHandler[
  Plot[f[x, a], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
   Prolog -> Dynamic@{Thin, 
       Line[{{p[[1]], 0}, {p[[1]], f[ p[[1]], a]}, {0, f[ p[[1]], a]}}], 
       Point[{p[[1]], f[ p[[1]], a]}]}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Dynamic@{p[[1]], f[ p[[1]], a]}],
  {"MouseMoved" :> (p = If[# =!= None, #, p] &@MousePosition["Graphics"])}],
{{a, 1, "a?"}, .1, 5, .1}]
```

[image: Manipulate output]

It also takes advantage of `Plot`'s adaptive graphing methods to deal with wiggly graphs.

Comment: Thanks, it looks interesting but I can't understand that code yet.

Comment: +1 for showing the lines of projection onto the axes. But I don't like that you get a pair of coordinates even when the cursor isn't on the curve.

Comment: @murray Thanks.  If asked, I could post a version in which the coordinates and projection lines disappear.  It's more complicated - perhaps I don't know the best way - and the OP seems to like Nasser's straightforward solution.

Comment: Yep, that's a dupe. I won't answer in that latest topic so feel free to include my comment into your answer there. ps. there is a nice syntax to keep last used coordinates after mouse exits: `p = MousePosition["Graphics", p]`.